# Where to place folder and files used by Docker app

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jar

I have installed Docker CE on Ubuntu Server. Everything went nice. The web app is running and so  mySql server. The problem is I have not Idea of where to place any content that the used by my docker app. Eg: I have a folder that contains folders and files that my docker app needs to work properly.

As per some documentation, I guess it has to go inside the container.The container is the root for the docker app inside.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches -

- You can mount the location using `-v` flag. Let's say the files that you want to include is code that you want to edit and debug. The mount option allows you to edit the code outside the docker container and run it within the container. Let's say your WORKDIR in docker container is `/app` and your files are located in your current directory, then you can add the flag as

`docker run -v $(pwd):/app -otherargs imagename`

- You can copy all contents into the docker image when building it. Place your Dockerfile along with the directory `dir` that you want to copy. Add the following line in your Dockerfile that will copy all contents of the directory `./dir` to `/app` within the image.

`COPY ./dir /app`

Comment: I think the question is "where in the container should he place his files" not how. I'm also confused and see some people placing it in `\usr\src\app` or `\usr\local\app` and some in `\home\app`

Comment: This will depend on what content you are placing and how you are accessing it. If you are both placing and accessing it from within the same docker container, in most cases it would not matter where you place it. However, if you are accessing the content in container A from container B, and container B is going to look into `\home\app` for the content, then that's where you want to place it in container A. If you have a specific use case, I would suggest asking this as a separate question.

Comment: It doesn't really matter in a container where you put the files.

Comment: The `/app` is not part of any standard I know of. Is it merely a convention adopted or invented by Docker authors? Why is it repeated everywhere?

Comment: It was just used as an example here since the OP had mentioned that they are building a web app. Perhaps that's the same reason you've seen it at other places. There is no reason for selecting a particular pathname like `/app` nor have I come across it as a convention. However, make sure that the mounted path on the container does not match any of the OS related directories inside the docker.